# Suggestions for my database design (Networking Users on the website)

Tags: sql, database-design

Imagine a scenario where -
All the users on the website can be affiliated to each other, i.e. something like be "friends" with each other and all.
The Database i want to design should be able to handle connections like these -
Suppose A is a friend of B (also implies B is a friend of A) wants to connect with D who is a friend of C who is a friend of B.
Think social networking.

My problem being how do i store these list of affiliates in a table?
What I've tried so far -
Table 1 -
Column 1 - User_id
Column 2 - User_id of affiliate
Having problems querying this table to give me a person's affiliates.

Table 2
Column 1 - User_id(A,B)
Column 2 - User_id of affiliate(B,A)
Each connection being shown by two rows instead of one, which makes querying easy.

But both of these seem too lame to me, do you guys know any better way of designing this kind of a database?

Comment: What do you want to do with the database?
You want to search for possible connections (eg. facebook's friend suggestion) or you just want to know if two are directly connectable upto some degree
How often will you have to execute a query to search relationship to some degree?

Comment: Database design depends entirely on how you are going to use the schemata

Comment: I want to know if how far apart are they, and maybe even suggest. But the thing is i will have to execute the query quite often. Right now i'd just be happy with a database structure that is enough to search for the person's friends with a single query.

Comment: are you using mysql/oracle or any other server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table 1.

Create a view over table 1 joining that table to itself to create table 2 as a view over table 1 with three columns.

Use both.